# Question about TRIGGERS with IF ELSE statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How would I get this trigger to work?

I intend to get the results as shown in the table below, but my current trigger does not seem to work. If I take out the IF ELSE section of the code, the details table would record "Frodo" with a null phone number in the details table.

I would want to let the trigger only activate when the phone_no is NOT NULL.

Customer Table

| id | name | phone_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Sam | 0123456789 |
| 0002 | Frodo | NULL |

Details Table

| id | name | category | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Sam | Phone | 0123456789 |

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_customer 
AFTER INSERT 
ON customer  
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF customer.phone_no IS NOT NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO details (id, name, category, details) 
        VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.name, "Phone", NEW.phone_no);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I keep getting an error on the [VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.name, "Phone", NEW.phone_no);], [END IF;] and [END;] lines of the code.

The error from MySQL Workbench for [VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.name, "Phone", NEW.phone_no);] states "statement is incomplete, expecting ';' ".

The error for MySQL Workbench for [END IF;] and [END;] states " 'END' is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN,... ".

I am not sure where the error is in the code and I would like to seek for some advice.

Would be thankful for any help or advice.

Comment: You don't appear to be setting delimiters?

Comment: I have just added the delimiters in the code above and now when I insert data into the customer table, I get the error code: 1109. "unknown table 'customer' in field list".

Comment: IF customer.phone_no  - You understood the the need to use NEW.phone_no in the insert but not in this condition - or perhaps you intended something else.

Answer (score 0):

Code now works with this.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_customer 
AFTER INSERT 
ON customer  
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.phone_no IS NOT NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO details (id, name, category, details) 
        VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.name, "Phone", NEW.phone_no);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Had to add delimiters and "IF NEW.phone_no" for it to work, as suggested by P.Salmon.